# ¿Cómo puedo traducir a python el siguien diagrama de flujo?

Tags: python

Tengo un diagrama de flujo que representa la estructura de iteración **for**, pero quisiera representarlo en Python.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo de código es lo siguiente:

```
i=1
for i in range(1,10):

    i=i+1
    print(i)
```

Comment: El diagrama supone la existencia del GOTO, que no Python no tiene.

Comment: Sí que se pueden hacer GOTOs en python, basta hackear un poco el _traceback_: https://gist.github.com/georgexsh/ede5163a294ced53c3e2369ccaa392cc

Comment: Que bueno que es un hack y no una caracteristica. El goto es muy confuso y, por lo menos yo, nunca lo necesité.

Comment: @Dante no es confuso. Solo hace el código más difícil de seguir. Eso no significa que no puedas usarlo, pero tampoco es para abusar de él. Además si un programador estructurado lo ve puede que le dé un infarto.

Comment: @mateo Por eso, si se lo usa de mas, se vuelve confuso de leer. Que pasaría ai tuvieras que usar goto para hacer 5 bucles anidados?

Answer (score 1):

Una de las opciones es usar for in, como intentaste

```
i=1
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

La otra, y se parece más al diagrama línea por línea, es con un bucle while:

```
i = 1
while True:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    if i > 10:
        break
```

La sentencia break en lugar de volver al inicio del while, lleva la ejecución a la línea siguiente posterior al mismo, haciendo que finalice el programa en este caso, pues no hay más líneas.

Comment: ¿por qué el voto negativo si se puede saber?

Comment: gracias Marcelo, me ayudó tu respuesta. No sé de que voto negativo hablas

Comment: La variable `i` al inicio del primer código es innecesaria

Comment: Sí @Christian, es para "parecerse" más al DF original. Perfecto zaraterdz, si la respuesta le sirvió no olvide tocar el tilde a su izquierda para marcarla como correcta.